# How to retrieve users' groups?

Tags: spring-security, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, spring-security-ldap

I've configured a Spring-based application with ADFS2.0, but I cannot retrieve users' groups.

I think it's a ADFS problem, but any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a claims rule:

Token-Groups - Unqualified Names --> Roles

Refer: [ADFS : Sending groups as claims](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2012/06/adfs-sending-groups-as-claims.html).